# how come my code won't use the input to search the dictionary, it keeps running the statement under ELSE

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python by creating a virtual coffee shop, I created a dictionary with the menu and the cook times and the code works great till I get to the input for what I want to order and it will not search the dictionary for the input and goes straight to the code after ELSE

```
import subprocess # adds subprocess to open window with subprocess.Popen
import sys # allows system to check command-line arguments
import time # adds time.sleep() function to create delays between lines

def print_with_typing(text):
    for char in text:
        print(char, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.025)

if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == "new_window": #this checks to see if sys.argv is storing command-line arguments
    print("Running in a new window")

    menu = {
        'Chicken Nuggets': {'cook_time': 10, 'price': 5},
        'Hamburger Fingers': {'cook_time': 15, 'price': 4.5},
        'Ham Sandwich': {'cook_time': 3, 'price': 3.5},
        'Coffee': {'cook_time': 1, 'price': 1.5},
        'Extra Strong Coffee': {'cook_time': 1, 'price': 2}, #add more items to dictionary as needed
    }

    print_with_typing("Hello!\nWelcome to Smooth Cream Coffee!!!!!!\n")

    name = input("what is your name?\n")
    time.sleep(.5) # use import time up top, the number is in seconds

    print_with_typing("\nHello " + name + "! Thank you so much for coming in today!!\n")
    time.sleep(1)

    menu_items = "\n".join(menu.keys())

    print_with_typing("We are serving a wide variety of the most flavorful foods paired with the richest coffee in America! \n\ntodays specials are:\n\n" + menu_items + "\n")
    while True:
        order = input("\nwhat would you like to order?\n")

        if order.lower() in menu:
            otime = menu[order]['cook_time']
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("\nSorry " + name + " we aren't serving " + order + ", please sellect one of the following items from our menu:\n")
            for item in menu:
                print(item)

    time.sleep(1)
    print_with_typing("\nThank you " + name + " I will be right out with your order, the " + order + " will be ready in " + otime + "\n\n")

    time.sleep(2)
    print_with_typing(name + ", Thank you for waiting, please enjoy your " + order + "\n")

    time.sleep(5)
    final = input("Here is your bill " + name + " did you enjoy your meal?\n")
    if final == "yes":
        time.sleep(1)
        print_with_typing("\nIm so glad you enjoyed your meal! please come back soon!")
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        print_with_typing("\nI am so sorry for your experience, we will apply a discount to your bill")
    input("\nPress Enter to exit.....")
else:

    print("\nOpening a new window.....")
    #opens a new window and execute the script
    
    subprocess.Popen(['start', 'cmd', '/k', 'python', 'lab.py', 'new_window'], shell=True)
```

I tried Mutiple variants of "If order.lower() in menu:" such as making it menu_items: or menu.keys(): but I can not figure out how to point it to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You're having trouble because the program is not correctly searching up user input in the menu dictionary. The following line of code is where the issue is:

```
if order.lower() in menu:
```

Here, `order.lower()` is converting the user's input to lowercase. However, the keys in the menu dictionary are in title case. So, the lowercase comparison will not match the keys as expected.

You can do the following instead:

```
if order.title() in menu:
```

Let me know if this helps.